# Returning Object Type from Oracle Procedure by partially populating it?

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate, global-temp-tables, oracle-objects

I have created an Object Type in Oracle as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Generic_MDMU_Scrub_Cols_OBJ as Object 
( 
  i_strTypeOfEntry varchar2(50),
  ID_SCRUB number,
  NM_DATA_COL1 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL2 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL3 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL4 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL5 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL6 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL7 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL8 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL9 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL10 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL11 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL12 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL13 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL14 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL15 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL16 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL17 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL18 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL19 varchar2(50),
  NM_DATA_COL20 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL1 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL2 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL3 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL4 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL5 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL6 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL7 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL8 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL9 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL10 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL11 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL12 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL13 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL14 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL15 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL16 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL17 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL18 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL19 varchar2(50),
  DATA_VAL20 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL1 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL2 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL3 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL4 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL5 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL6 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL7 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL8 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL9 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL10 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL11 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL12 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL13 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL14 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL15 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL16 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL17 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL18 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL19 varchar2(50),
  OLD_DATA_VAL20 varchar2(50)
);
/
```

Now I want to write a Procedure which returns this Object Type as the output parameter to the calling Java code. Basically there are couple of tables which store columns like `OLD_DATA_VAL1...OLD_DATA_VAL20` and `DATA_VAL1...DATA_VAL120` and similarly another table having columns `NM_DATA_COL1...NM_DATA_COL20` and depending on various use cases only 3 or 5 or any number of columns will have values and other would be null. Eg- `OLD_DATA_VAL1,OLD_DATA_VAL2,OLD_DATA_VAL3,DATA_VAL1,DATA_VAL2,DATA_VAL3,NM_DATA_COL1,NM_DATA_COL2,NM_DATA_COL3` have values and other columns are null. I have created a meta table which would give me comma separated column names.

Now when I try using type or cursor, the problem is since all the values are not populated it throws error.
My procedure is something like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDPR (
    in_id_scrub IN NUMBER
)
AS
  V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA VARCHAR2(500);
  V_COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA VARCHAR2(500);
  V_COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW VARCHAR2(500);
  sqlstmt  VARCHAR2(2000);
  V_Generic_MDMU_Scrub_Cols Generic_MDMU_Scrub_Cols_OBJ;

SELECT COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA, COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA, COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW INTO V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA, V_COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA, V_COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW FROM MDDBO.MDMU_METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDTB WHERE ID_WORKFLOW_MAINTENANCE_MSTR = in_id_wf;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA || ' --- ' || V_COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA || ' --- ' || V_COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW);

 sqlstmt:= 'select ' || V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA || ',' || V_COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA || ',' || V_COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW || ',AUTO.TYPE_OF_ENTRY i_strTypeOfEntry FROM MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_DATA_MDTB DATA, MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_LOG_MDTB MSTR, MDDBO.MDMU_MAP_WORK_FLOW_MDTB WKF,
 MDDBO.MDMU_METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDTB AUTO WHERE
 MSTR.ID_TBL = WKF.ID_WF and
 MSTR.id_scrub = :in_id_scrub and MSTR.id_scrub = DATA.id_scrub and
 AUTO.ID_WORKFLOW_MAINTENANCE_MSTR = WKF.ID_WF';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlstmt);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstmt
  INTO V_Generic_MDMU_Scrub_Cols
  USING in_id_scrub;


 EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error '||sqlerrm);

END METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDPR;
```

But it throws Oracle error like below in case of type-

```
error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
```

Some Oracle Guy suggested using Global Temporary Table (GTT) but I believe they are common for all the sessions and are not viable here. So, if I want to partially populate but I am not sure if thats the best case here or something can be done with object like partially initializing unused values to null.

**UPDATE**

Printing the dbms_ouput from the 2 statements to make thing clearer

Output1:

```
DATA_VAL1,DATA_VAL2,DATA_VAL3,DATA_VAL4,DATA_VAL5 --- OLD_DATA_VAL1,OLD_DATA_VAL2,OLD_DATA_VAL3,OLD_DATA_VAL4,OLD_DATA_VAL5 --- NM_DATA_COL1,NM_DATA_COL2,NM_DATA_COL3,NM_DATA_COL4,NM_DATA_COL5
```

Output2:

```
select DATA_VAL1,DATA_VAL2,DATA_VAL3,DATA_VAL4,DATA_VAL5,OLD_DATA_VAL1,OLD_DATA_VAL2,OLD_DATA_VAL3,OLD_DATA_VAL4,OLD_DATA_VAL5,NM_DATA_COL1,NM_DATA_COL2,NM_DATA_COL3,NM_DATA_COL4,NM_DATA_COL5,AUTO.TYPE_OF_ENTRY i_strTypeOfEntry FROM MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_DATA_MDTB DATA, MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_LOG_MDTB MSTR, MDDBO.MDMU_MAP_WORK_FLOW_MDTB WKF,
 MDDBO.MDMU_METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDTB AUTO WHERE
 MSTR.ID_TBL = WKF.ID_WF and
 MSTR.id_scrub = :in_id_scrub and MSTR.id_scrub = DATA.id_scrub and
 AUTO.ID_WORKFLOW_MAINTENANCE_MSTR = WKF.ID_WF
```

**Main Issue** -  Having fewer dynamically selected columns compared to the number of columns in the Object Type. (See Output 1, there can be 3 each also)

**Update 2**

Now my main concern is how to get the values from the dynamic sql formed with variable number of selected columns.

Using below query I am able to get the column headers but somehow not able to get the col values. My query would return only one row-

```
OPEN rc_ FOR sqlstmt using in_id_scrub;
   c_ := DBMS_SQL.to_cursor_number(rc_);
   DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c_, col_count_, desc_tab_);
   FOR i_ IN 1..col_count_ LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(desc_tab_(i_).col_name);     
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c_, i_, desc_tab_(i_).COL_NAME, 2000);
   END LOOP;
   res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(c_, TRUE);
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
   FOR i IN 1..col_count_ LOOP
        tab1.EXTEND;
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c_, i, tab1(tab1.LAST));
        --DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c_, i, tab1(i));
        --DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c_, i, arr1);
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab1(1));
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c_);

  FOR l_row IN 1 .. tab1.COUNT
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (tab1 (l_row));
      END LOOP;
```

Comment: No, GTTs are **not** common for all the sessions, their data is private to the session that inserts it.

Comment: So it that the best solution for this case or we can still use object type?

Comment: I don't know.  The data created in a GTT by a PL/SQL procedure wouldn't be available to a Java program connecting via a different session.  I don't know enough about using Java to say whether that would be the case.

Comment: Tony thanks pls don't consider Java. Think I have to locally run it in SqlDeveloper. Can we do this using Object? Can you post a solution for this using Object if possible or any pseudocode using GTT?

Comment: Re Update 2: DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH will only return 1 row; you need to use DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE, and then DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS in a loop until no more rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem here seems to be this line:

```
sqlstmt:= 'select ' || V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA || ',' || V_COL_NAMES_OLD_SCRUB_DATA || ',' || V_COL_HEADER_MAP_WORKFLOW || ',AUTO.TYPE_OF_ENTRY i_strTypeOfEntry FROM MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_DATA_MDTB DATA, MDDBO.MDMU_SCRUB_LOG_MDTB MSTR, MDDBO.MDMU_MAP_WORK_FLOW_MDTB WKF,
 MDDBO.MDMU_METADATA_AUTOMATION_MDTB AUTO WHERE
 MSTR.ID_TBL = WKF.ID_WF and
 MSTR.id_scrub = :in_id_scrub and MSTR.id_scrub = DATA.id_scrub and
 AUTO.ID_WORKFLOW_MAINTENANCE_MSTR = WKF.ID_WF';
```

...as I understand it, because e.g. V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA might be null?

In that case a simple NVL should suffice:

```
sqlstmt:= 'select ' || NVL(V_COL_NAMES_CURRENT_SCRUB_DATA, 'null as col1') || ...
```

So now instead of:

```
select ,,SOMECOL,...
```

you would get:

```
select null as col1, null as col2, SOMECOL, ...
```

Comment: No any of V_COL_XXX won't be null. Problem is it would have fewer number of columns compared to that in Oracle Object type. I will update my question with the DBMS output and the meta table entry to make it clearer.

Comment: Can't you just dynamically concatenate on as many `, null as colNN` columns as your type needs?

Comment: To do that I need to know the column names, I know the column names which have values through another table but column names not having values are not stored. What would be the best practice here to be able to do that. I wished if we could instantiate all elements of an object with null and when we do an into clause only those columns which we select would get updated!

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really following you.  You are dynamically creating a SELECT statement and you need it to return N columns, where N is the number of attributes in your type.  You know how many columns you have added to the select (say M), so you need to "pad" this out to N columns by adding ', null as colNN` (N-M) times? e.g. if your type has 100 attributes but your dynamic select only returns 42 then you know you need to add `null as col43, null as col44, ..., null as col100`.  So you can write a loop to do that. What am I missing?

Comment: yes you got my point. In fact I too was thinking of adding using contructor to initialize object where I would loop and create N-M null, clause to initialize the object. The problem I see with Oracle is we have to provide all the arguments in order rather than in any programming language where we can set any field by using just name.

Comment: So is the issue that the default constructor is not what you need? If so, then write your own.

Comment: William, Tony, please find Update 2